# Windows cmd file not executing call anymore

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a cmd file that was working the whole time during my testing and from one minute to the other it doesn't execute my call to another batch file anymore.

The command not working anymore is:

```
call myfile.bat
```

Now the only thing that happens at this line is an error: "The provided program can not be executed"

I don't know if it's the exact English version as my system is in German, but it should be like that or similar.

Anyone has an idea why it's not executing my batch file anymore?

Comment: Is `myfile.bat` in the same folder as the calling batch file, or somewhere in `%PATH%`?

Comment: What is happening inside `myfile.bat`? Show us the code.

Answer (score 1):

1. virus infection
2. hard disk crash
3. insufficient permission
4. lock by administration
5. memory leak
6. unstable power supply
7. processor overheating
8. flash of lightning
9. general failure
10. unknown reason

Comment: You know that 9 and 10 is not very helpful?!

Comment: @Thomas I know :) but do you know that your question is not very helpful? We're not being given the entire input-line, output-line, desired-output-line, processing method and environment conditions.

Answer (score 0):

1. myfile.bat got overwritten.
2. Are you now executing as a different user?

Comment: No, the file name is still the same and also the user.